# when I try to add my theme.css in my wordpress header.php file then page.php is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, fixed

In my header.php I added this code for CSS:

```
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/css/theme.css">
```

When I remove this code from header.php, my page.php is working but not showing the text and image properly. (CSS is not working) Like this:

[image: image: when css not add in my header.php]

But when I add this code in my header.php file then in my page.php file, I see a blank page. None of the text or images are showing. Like this:

[image: Image: a blank page after add css in my header.php file]

How i can fix this?

Comment: You have a PHP error in the code that is preventing it from being displayed.

Comment: Right click -> View Page Source, is the `href` attribute rendered correctly in HTML?

Comment: try to simply replace this <?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?> by the url if you alread know it

Answer (score 1):

This is not best practice. The proper way to add scripts and styles to your theme is to enqueue them in the `functions.php` files.

Go through this link once :-
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/